# How do I change site url to my new domain?

Tags: domain

So, i need to change domain name. Here´s what I have tried. First I changed the name servers on my new domain towards the web hotel I'm using. Second, I logged in to c-panel and parked the new domain. Then I went to WordPress adminpanel - settings - general and changed the site url.

After this i thought the only thing left would be to update the permalinks. What happens is the new url does work (it was redirected in the first place) but the site looks broken up, which i took as something that would maybe happen before the permalinks where changed. But I can't log in to the adminpanel, mu hosting said there where no debug messages sp they didn't know what was going on. changed back the site url in cpanel. and tried again with all plugins deactivated, same thing.

How do i see of my domain has  propagated correctly after change of name servers? Did a trace route, the ip´s doesn't match my name servers exactly. Should it?

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress and some themes store configurations and URLs in serialized data, and the Search & Replace plugin does not handle those to correctly change a domain in the database.

And don't use simple SQL change queries in the database via adminer or phpmyadmin. A simple SQL query won't correctly handle serialized data.

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for full details on moving Wordpress and [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to correctly find/replace URLs in the database.

Comment: +1 Following the Codex instructions on how to move a site has always worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your site is broken up is because all of your links need to be updated, as wordpress has a habit of using complete URL's as opposed to relative links.

You need to update your database and change all of the references from your old domain name to your new domain name.

You can use PHPMYAdmin from the cPanel and update your tables manually with something like:

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

The "easy button" for this is to use something like this: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

You put this in your domain root, and it works quite well for doing a find and replace on the WP Database without having to know how to use MYSQL.  If you use the search and replace file, make sure you remove it afterwards.

Comment: Don't use simple SQL change queries in the database via adminer or phpmyadmin. WordPress and some themes store configurations and URLs in serialized data, which a simple SQL query won't correctly handle.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding this to wp-config: 
     define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
     define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');