# Why is my site still showing insecure icon even if I have SSL certificate?

Tags: plugins, images, redirect

I have a Valid SSL certificate. My home page, About page, and Hire Page are insecure. I have found out my images on those pages are requesting and accessing an image from HTTP. I used Plugin, every one of them. It didn't work. I tried deleting the image and uploading it again. It didn't work either. Updated .htacess file, problem not solved. Can anyone assist me?  https://rupeshghimire.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the urls in your database to use https. All requests from your website need to be https for your site to be secure.

Comment: My main problem is few images are loading in http, instead of https. Any idea how can i solve it ?

Comment: "You need to change the urls in your database to use https."

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157883/how-do-i-change-site-url-to-my-new-domain

Comment: Have you checked my site? why is my BLOG and PODCAST menu is secure then? I have run the Search and Replace plugin already. It didn't work. Can you be specific, what needs to be done?

Comment: You're using Elementor which you didn't mention in your question. Elementor has a tool that performs the search and replace. Use that to switch to https and then clear the elementor and other caches on your site.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, really appreciate it. Problem solved

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and mark this answer as accepted if this solved your problem.